# How to solve "file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed" while inserting xml data into oracle table?

Tags: plsql, directory, utl-file

I followed these steps to insert XML data into an Oracle table:

1. Created one directory and created one table. What are the columns having that XML file I created the table also.
2. Now I'm inserting the data into that table I'm getting an error which I need help with.

```
 ExtractValue(Value(x),'//Costs') as Costs           
    FROM   TABLE(XMLSequence(Extract(XMLType(bfilename('MY_DIR', 'test.xml'), 
    nls_charset_id('UTF8') ),'/PODetails/POHeader'))) x;
```

Error:

```
ORA-22288: file or LOB operation FILEOPEN failed
The system cannot find the path specified.
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_LOB", line 523
ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 287
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: We would need more information to assist you in this as there could be a lot of reasons.  eg Was the directory object created as the same user as you are executing the sql as. If not does your user that you are executing the SQL as have privileges granted to directory.  Does Oracle user have permissions on the file system directory. Have you used correct case for file and directory (they are case sensitive).  There are other potential causes as well.  But hope that gives you some ideas where to start looking, and then you can update the question.